# Which is correct - '+' or '|' in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I've seen both of these notations in various threads and I'd like to know which is correct?
Or, is there no functional difference?

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait + UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
```

or

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
```

Comment: It depends.  In most cases either should be fine.  `|` is probably a little "safer", especially if the API designer has provided "convenience" options that combine several individual options.

Comment: `+` is fine in _this_ case. But if you're modifying an existing mask, + is definitely not safe. `|` is semantically correct, and you should use it even when you can get away with using `+`, just so you don't pick up the habit.

Comment: Just because `+` happens to work like a logical OR in *some* cases is not a good reason to use it. It should only be used when addition is required.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the explanations - I thought I might get down voted for what seemed 'too simple' of a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, `|` is the correct operator to use for bitfields.

While other operators might work and yield similar results it is semantically wrong to use them and confusing for other programmers reading your code.

Using `+` (or `^` which has a similar effect in this case) just obfuscates the meaning. In a code review I would reject it.

Answer (score 2):

### The '|' is better

For the purpose of combining bit mask flags, they are *almost* the same. You have:

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 | 0 = 0

0 + 1 = 1
0 | 1 = 1

1 + 0 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
```

However, they are different when you do:

```
1 + 1 = 0 // and 1 goes to higher bit
1 | 1 = 1
```

You can have a '1 + 1' case, when you combine same flags. It can happen by mistake, when you modify existing mask, or when you do something less trivial, say you get those flags by calling other methods, then you accumulate them in some variable, and it is possible to get the same flag several times.

In this case, only `|` gives correct results, so I say that it is better to get a habit of always using `|`.

It would also make your code more readable by others.

Comment: As long as the implementor did their bit flags properly.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

They are both have the same result in this particular case, but `|` is preferred because it's a more correct operator for bitfields where arithmetic is possible but usually meaningless.

For example, if you have the interface orientation in a variable and you want to enable or disable a particular value, using `+` can lead to unexpected behavior.

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMask mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
// some other code ...
// Now I want to (incorrectly!) enable portrait, without checking it first
mask = mask + UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
// mask now counterintuitively == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown
```

If instead you user `|`, you can ensure that you are operating correctly on the bit field:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMask mask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
// ...
// Now I want to (correctly!) enable portrait, without checking it first
mask = mask | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // mask is what you would expect it to be.
```